# PROVEtech:TA doesnt start gRPC Server defined in TM.ini

Tags: testing, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using PROVEtech:TA 2021 SE SP3 64 bit.

I have defined the gRPC Address / Port to listen to in the TM.ini defined in the TA.ini (shown in settings) as such.

```
[gRPC1]
Listen=127.0.0.1:9876
```

Restarted P:TA.
A call from a gRPC Client gives me this error:

```
Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061)
```

I checked the ports the P:TA Computer is listening to and it does not show the TCP in the following command:

`netstat -n -a -o`

It used to work, then P:TA crashed and had to be reinstalled / repaired, now it doesn't work anymore. Does anyone have any pointers as to where to check / what to do?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was **multiple instances** of Provetech:TA **installed** on the computer.

We had `PROVEtech:TA 2021 SE SP3 64 bit` and `PROVEtech:TA 2022 SP3 64 bit` installed on the device.

This apparently stopped the gRPC Server from initializing.

If you run into this issue, **try uninstalling all instances** of PROVEtech:TA from your device - **then reinstalling the instance you require**. This should solve this issue.